# Do you have any simple hash function that takes first three letter?

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, cs50

I'm working at `cs50` speller.
This is my hash function. It works well. But I think it's not really good because there's a lot of `if` condition.
I try to make a different table for every word that have apostrophe at the first two letter (ex, A', B', C').

So I used buckets (26 x 26 x 26) + 26 = 17602;

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    /*
        this is HASHING algorithms in which we return value with checking first three letter
        make sure every word set to lowercase so we can easily convert as integer value or alphabetical index
        and also set every first element before first letter to be a place for every apostrophe that comes at second word

        [A'=0] [Aaa=1] [Aab=2] ... [Aay=25] [Aaz=26] ... [B'=677] [Baa=678] --- base 676 number
                n = ( 677*first(word ) 26*second(word) + third(word) ) + 1;
    */

    int hash_value = 0;

    if(strlen(word) <= 1)                                       // if there's only one word calculate that word, store to element after apostrophe
    {
        hash_value = ((677 * (tolower(word[0]) - 97)) + 1);
        return hash_value;
    }
    else if(!isalpha(word[1]))                                  // if second word contain apostrophe just calucalte first word
    {
        hash_value = (677 * (tolower(word[0]) - 97));
        return hash_value;
    }
    else if(strlen(word) <= 2)                                  // if there's two word calculate that two word, store to element after apostrophe
    {
        hash_value = ((677 * (tolower(word[0]) - 97)) + (27 * (tolower(word[1]) - 97))) + 1;
        return hash_value;
    }
    else if(!isalpha(word[2]))                                  // if third word contain apostrophe just calucalte first and two word
    {
        hash_value = ((677 * (tolower(word[0]) - 97)) + (27 * (tolower(word[1]) - 97))) + 1;
        return hash_value;
    }
    else
    {
        hash_value = ((677 * (tolower(word[0]) - 97)) + (27 * (tolower(word[1]) - 97)) + (tolower(word[2]) - 97)) + 1;
        return hash_value;
    }
}
```

It's actually works quite well.

```
./speller texts/lalaland.txt
WORDS MISSPELLED:     955
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        17756
TIME IN load:         0.02
TIME IN check:        0.02
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.00
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.05
```

I just don't like it the way I used a lot of `ELSE..IF` condition.
So maybe you want to help me with better code (with take first three letters).

Comment: you can take a pointer to first char, use a while loop and increment pointer.

Comment: Kevinkun: Important specification needed: Should the hash be case insensitive?  It looks like you want that, but best to be clear.

Comment: In 2nd `if`, code has `hash_value = (677 * (tolower(word[0]) - 97));`.  Is the +1 missing?

Comment: store `strlen(word)` in a variable instead of calling it again and again like that

Answer (score 1):

In some ways, you are implementing a `for` loop with `if` statements.  An idea like

```
int hash = 0;
for (char *current = word; *current != '\0'; current++) {
    if (current == &word[2]) break;
    hash += hash(*current);
}
```

might permit you to avoid the if statements, because now the end-of-index handling is repeated in the loop.

Comment: OP's hash limits to the first 3 `char`.  This runs to the end of the potentially long string and is not case insensitive.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ideas are not finished programs.  Typically, by the time one starts to deal with hashing, one can exit a for loop after three iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I inderstand the logic of this hash but:

1. tolower returns the same char if the parameter in not upper letter. No need to check if it is alpha

```
unsigned int hash1(const char *word)
{

    unsigned int result;

    result = (!!word[0]) * (677 * (tolower(word[0]) - 97));
    result += (word[0] && word[1]) * (27 * (tolower(word[1]) - 97));
    result += (word[0] && word[1] && word[2]) * (tolower(word[2]) - 97) + 1;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: this answer only works if the first three letters are in the range a...z and/or A...Z   For a word like the monsanto brand `3m` the result is a LARGE NEGATIVE hash

Comment: @user3629249 it cant be negative

Comment: using the example `3m` the result is: `1 * 677 * (51-97)` = −31142

Comment: I do not use **`signed`** integers and result cannot be negative

Answer (score 0):

Simply test `isalpha()` and take advantage that `isalpha(0)` is false.
With only up to 3 `char`, a few `if()` suffice.

```
_Static_assert(isalpha(0) == 0, "isalpha(0) unexpectedly true");

unsigned int hashf(const char *word) {
  // best to use unsigned char access for tolower() to avoid UB.
  const unsigned char *uword = word;

  unsigned hash = 677u * (tolower(uword[0]) - 'a') + 1;
  if (isalpha(uword[0]) && isalpha(uword[1])) {
    hash += 27u * (tolower(uword[1]) - 'a');
    if (isalpha(uword[2])) hash += tolower(uword[2]) - 'a';
  }
  return hash;  // see below
}
```

---

Simplification possibility: no real need for `- 97` or `- 'a'`.  We are making a *hash*, but obliges a final modulo.

```
  #define BUCKET_N 17602u
  return hash % BUCKET_N;
```

IAC, a final modulo by the bucket size makes for robust hash.  Consider OP's  `hash("~")`.  OP's code assumes character values - 97 are in the range 0 to 25, yet what happens when a character is `á`?  Watch out for character vales outside `[0  CHAR_MAX]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a for loop I wrote, that basically does the same thing as yours. Pretty easy to add to the number of letters to hash, up to 4, 5, etc., by changing the 3 in the for loop, and of course updating the bucket size.

```
// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // Get word length
    int word_len = strlen(word);
    int hash_code = 0;

    // Numbers for multiplying via indexing in a for loop
    int multiplier = 1;

    // Loop over letters in the word
    for (int i = 0; i < word_len && i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(word[i]))
            return hash_code;

        hash_code += (tolower(word[i]) - 'a') * multiplier;

        if (word_len == 1)
            return hash_code;

        multiplier *= 26;
    }

    return hash_code + 1;
}
```

Here's the output on that

```
./speller texts/lalaland.txt
WORDS MISSPELLED:     955
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        17756
TIME IN load:         0.02
TIME IN check:        0.04
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.00
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.06
```